# Help to fix jquery sortable for ordered list

Tags: jquery

Please see the demo here
http://trainee4.afixiindia.com/pratap/ui/shopping_cart.html

When I click on the number and try to drag for sortable,its not happening.But when I drag the li ,its working

"It mayn't be done with an ordered list because the numbers aren't represented in HTML. I have to use an unstyled, unordered list and manage the numbers myself.":-Its a solution I think

Is there any solution.?

Comment: @Pryabrata: It's nice you show the demo, but add your code here.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to your `#cart ol` style:

```
list-style-position: inside;
```

Comment: Thank you ,would you please tell me why any one put -1 my question, is there anything wrong approach to ask.

Comment: @Priyabrata: I didn't down-vote your question but based on @Nobita's comment, adding a demo is great addition to the question and it's actually a plus, but to maintain clear questions/answers in the community (future readers) adding the code here would help in case your link went down for some reason.